# Shorter more efficient way to tackle this codewars challenge?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm fairly new to JavaScript (and development in general). I wanted to try a challenge from Codewars. The challenge was to process a string through a function that would flip any words that were over 5 characters and return the original string with those flipped words. Here's the code I came up with (It did work!).

```
//this function turns each word into an array that will get flipped.
let wordFlipper = (word) => { 
  var splitWord = word.split('');   //convert word to array
  var reversedWord = splitWord.reverse();   //flips the indexes for the array
  var joinReversedWord = reversedWord.join('').toString();   //turns array back to a string.
  return joinReversedWord;
}

function spinWords(phrase){
    let finalArray = [];
    let wordsToArray = phrase.split(' ');
    const processFlipWords = wordsToArray.forEach(word => {
      if (word.toString().length > 4) {
      var flippedWord = wordFlipper(word); //here's where we call the function wordFlipper()
      finalArray.push(flippedWord);
      }
      else {
      finalArray.push(word);
      }
    });
    return finalArray.join(' ');
}
```

How would you experts suggest writing this? I'm sure I'm not being too efficient at writing this code.

Thank you!

[Here's what it looks like inside codewars!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0bpv.png)

Comment: Please post code that "did work!" to [codereview.se]. SO is for code that failed 

Comment: @hc_dev oh you're right! I'll take note of that next time! Sorry this was only my second post ever! Got that bookmarked now!

Comment: Alright, once you tried you will love the reviewers there. Well asked question for the second time  Keep on posting, looking forward to more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a **regular expression** to match *5 or more word characters* (`\w{5,}`), and have a **replacer function** (`String.replace()`) return the reversed (`reverse()`) word:

```js
const spinWords = phrase => phrase.replace(
  /\w{5,}/g,
  word => [...word].reverse().join('')
);

console.log(spinWords('foo barbar more words go here'));
```

`\w` matches a word character - something from A to Z, case-insensitive, or a digit, or an underscore.

The brackets indicates the number of times to repeat the previous token. `{5,}` starts with a 5 (so, "at least 5") and has nothing after the comma ("up to any number").

Then `/g`, the global flag, matches and replaces every substring that matches this pattern, not just the first.

The callback function runs for every matched substring, where the argument is the matched substring, and what is returned gets replaced at that point in the original string.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. Thank you so much! I'm going to study how your code there works. I haven't yet seen the ellipsis being used (I'm not fully done with my javascript course). I also don't know what /\w{5,}/g means unfortunately lol. I'm hoping it all makes more sense soon! Thank you!

Comment: `\w` matches a word character - something from A to Z, case-insensitive, or a digit, or an underscore. The brackets indicates the number of times to repeat the previous token. `{5,}` starts with a 5 (so, "at least 5") and has nothing after the comma ("up to any number"). Then `/g`, the global flag, matches and replaces *every* substring that matches this pattern, not just the first. The callback function runs for every matched substring, where the argument is the matched substring, and what is returned gets replaced at that point in the original string.

Comment: Got it! I'm researching all those now for future use. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @CertainPerformance You explained the regex comprehensibly. Could directly paste to your answer. I edited already to highlight essential parts 